# Post-Redirect-Get pattern, exit() function porpuse

Tags: php, redirect, exit

I am trying to understand the pattern Post-Redirect-Get and in several examples the people put a `exit()` after the redirect, like so:

```
if ($_POST) {
   // Execute code (such as database updates) here.

   // Redirect to this page.
   header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit();
}
```

My question is about the `exit()` function. What is the porpuse of it? For me, it is never readed because the page is redirect before  "php interpreter" arrive there.

Comment: I do not see the reason why downvote. As I said, the exit() function is no called, but I was searching for might an unknown-fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, is not called.

But before you asked a question you could did this little test to check if it was called.

```
if ($_POST) {
   // Execute code (such as database updates) here.

   // Redirect to this page.
   header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $fp = fopen("log.txt", "a");
   fwrite($fp, "called");
   fclose($fp);
   exit();
}
```

So if you see a file named log.txt it's because exit function was called, if there is no file means that exit wasn't called.

Comment: I did it, as I said. Thought that I was forgetting some trick about it.